# Golf a Golfing Language

Tags: code-golf, language-design

Design a language and golf its interpreter so that it solves the following programming challenges in as few bytes as possible:

- Hello World
- cat
- Fizz Buzz
- List the first \$n\$ primes
- Fibonacci Sequence
- Sort a numerical list
- Balanced parentheses/brackets/braces test
- Rule 110 (as a proof of Turing completeness)

## Challenge Definitions

### Hello World

No input.

Output this exact text:

```
Hello World!
```

### cat

Input: text

Output: the same text

### Fizz Buzz

Input: an integer \$n\$

Output: all numbers from \$1\$ to \$n\$, with multiples of 3 replaced with "Fizz", multiples of 5 replaced with "Buzz", and multiples of 15 replaced with "FizzBuzz" or "Fizz Buzz".

### List the first \$n\$ primes

Input: an integer \$n\$

Output: the first \$n\$ prime numbers, defined as positive integers which are divisible only by 1 and themselves.

### Fibonacci Sequence

Defined formally as:

$$
f_1 = 1
$$
$$
f_2 = 1
$$
$$
f_{n+2} = f_n + f_{n+1}
$$

The first few Fibonacci numbers are: \$1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55\$

Input: an integer \$n\$

Output: the first \$n\$ Fibonacci numbers.

### Sort a numerical list

Input: A list of integers. May be empty. May contain duplicate numbers.

Output: All of the elements of that list sorted in ascending order.

### Balanced parentheses / brackets / braces test

Input: A possibly empty string containing printable ASCII characters

Output: truthy if parentheses, brackets, and braces are all balanced and matching, falsy otherwise

Examples:

```
                 --> truthy
non-empty string --> truthy
[]               --> truthy
(}               --> falsy
()[]             --> truthy
bl[ah]           --> truthy
1)               --> falsy
([]{}((()))[{}]) --> truthy
([{}])}          --> falsy
```

### Rule 110

[Wikipedia article on Rule 110](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_110)

For quick reference, given a list of cells which are either on or off, the next state is generated from each cell and its neighbors, using the following table of rules:

```
current pattern  111 110 101 100 011 010 001 000
new cell          0   1   1   0   1   1   1   0
```

Cells outside the list are considered off and must be generated on demand when they turn on.

Input: A rule 110 state, in any convenient representation

Output: The next rule 110 state, with at least one extra cell added to the left side if necessary.

Implementing Rule 124 (Rule 110's mirror image) is also acceptable, as this can be interpreted as Rule 110 on a reversed list.

## Rules

- Programs written in your language can use any convenient IO method
- Hello World and cat are allowed to output a single trailing newline.
- The full range of 32-bit signed integers must be supported, at minimum, for all numeric challenges.
- The golfing language may not be a literal subset of its host language.
- Your language interpreter must be non-trivially implemented. All of the following loopholes are banned: (I reserve the right to ban more if the need arises)

  - Your interpreter simply calls out to `eval` or equivalent
  - A 1:1 remapping is applied to the program text and then interpreted by another function or external program.

## Scoring

$$
Score = 3 \times I + P 
$$

Where:

- \$I\$ is the length of the interpreter, in bytes
- \$P\$ is the sum of the length of all challenge programs, in bytes

Lowest score wins.

It's better to have a smaller interpreter than short programs, making builtins potentially more costly than a smaller instruction set.

Comment: To what degree is it OK to overfit the language to these specific tasks?

Comment: How do you quantify those loopholes? If you ban "simply call eval," I'll make a language that reverses the source code and then evals that. Or base64 decodes the source and then evals it. Or... You get the picture. I do like the 3:1 ratio favoring a short interpreter over shorter programs, but some use of eval is *the* obvious solution under those conditions. Maybe just ban eval entirely?

Comment: @DLosc Do X Without Y - define "eval".

Comment: @HighlyRadioactive Well, exactly. I love language-design questions, and I like the premise here, but I'm afraid it may just degenerate into a bunch of rules-lawyering.

Comment: Let's just not do it. If the answers turns into a bunch of rules-lawyering, don't mind them - there's no such thing called "accepted answer" or "the one winner" now, only a serious contender.

Comment: How should the interpreter take the input of the interpreted program?

Comment: Oh, and one last thing, this challenge should have a chatroom to allow collabration.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/162093/build-a-golfing-language-with-me) (and all sub-challenges - i.e. [Hello World](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world) - are related as well I guess)

Comment: I hope you know that implementing rule 110 as you have specified may not guarantee Turing Completeness.  Rule 110 has been show TC under a very specific background pattern which is *not* the one you have asked to implement.

Comment: Why is this challenge closed? This looks clear enough to me.

Comment: @petStorm +1. Bubbler, explain. When it's in the sandbox you said nothing, and when it's posted to main you closed it immediately.

Comment: This challenge seems fine to me too, not sure why it was closed

Comment: I'm confused how people are confused why this is closed. There are multiple highly-upvoted comments with unanswered questions that, I as see it, are fundamental to understanding what the challenge is about. I wouldn't even call them nitpicking or rules lawyering, but asking about the core idea of the challenge, without which I don't know how to start writing a competitive valid answer.

Comment: I should have said more explicitly what I'm unclear about. Ideally I'd have caught this in the Sandbox, but alas. Since we're being only scored on specific tasks, I expect the best strategy, if allowed, is to not to write a golfing language, but something doing these exact tasks in an existing language. An actual interpreter just wastes bytes, so solutions would do it only as far as as required. And the challenge says that the language be "non-trivially implemented", but I find that unclear and/or exploitable, and the "I reserve the right to ban more if the need arises" is far from reassuring.

Comment: A possible solution to the interpreter issue: Have a minimum size of the interpreter. This makes it so `eval` solutions don't help, since it'd be better to use up that space. The only peoblem is that it might unfairly benefit interpreters in golfing langs, though that was going to happen anyway